# Como filtrar anuncios por categorias en PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tengo una base de Datos en Mysql, la tabla "anuncios", que tiene un campo de categoría, las categorias se crean bien, sin problemas se almacenan en la base de datos. Ahora, en la vista principal del proyecto, quiero tener un select que liste todas las categorias existentes, y que al seleccionar alguna, haga un filtro y me muestre solamente los anuncios con esa categoria.

[image: Los anuncios en la vista principal se muestran de esta manera, en cards de Bootstrap4]

```
//Conexion con la base
mysql_connect("localhost","nacional_admin","adminguia2019");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

//selección de la base de datos con la que vamos a trabajar 
mysql_select_db("nacional_admin"); 

                $sSQL="SELECT nombre FROM categoria ORDER BY id";
                $result=mysql_query($sSQL);

                echo '<select name="categoria" id="categoria">';

                 //Generamos el menu desplegable
                 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                 {echo '<option>'.$row["nombre"];}

                 echo '</select>';
?>
```

Con este código puedo listar en los options del select sin problemas las categorias, faltaria poder hacer ese filtro al seleccionar alguna de esas categorias.

Comment: categoría en tu tabla **anuncio** es una llave foranea a la tabla categorías? Cómo se llama tu columna que tiene la FK (llave foranea) a categorias? y si haces un **select * from anuncios where categoria=categoria_buscada**?

Comment: exacto, mi campo "categoria" dentro de la tabla "anuncios" es una clave foranea, que estira desde la tabla "categorias"

Comment: En realidad tu pregunta es como hacer una consulta en dos tablas, deberias agregar tus tablas y la consulta que intentastes